# Is it possible to tell MathJax to use fonts for specific languages?

Tags: javascript, html, latex, fonts, mathjax

I love MathJax, but it does not support Cyrillic (or at least it looks so). I tried such simple text as an expression into [this official example](http://mathjax.org/mathjax/test/sample-dynamic.html) - it shows all English 
letters but no Russian.

> Mother Phather Love Forever Мама мыла Раму

So I wonder - how to extend MathJax to support non English languages?

Answer (score 2):

Well, when I enter `мыла`, I do get the Cyrillic for it, but it will depend on the fonts you have available on your computer, and what browser you are using.  IE, in particular, may not find the characters on its own without suggesting a font for it to work from.  So you might try something like

```
{\large\style{font-family:Times}{\text{мыла}}}
```

instead, which should work better.  My results for this are

[image: Cyrillic in MathJax]
<sub>(source: [dpvc at www.math.union.edu](http://www.math.union.edu/%7Edpvc/transfer/mathjax/Cyrillic.png))</sub>

which seems right to me (though I don't know Russian).

It is also possible to configure MathJax to use the current page font for the results of `\text{}` macros, which might help you as well.  The page you cite does not have that configuration, however, so forcing the font as in the example above is required in this case.  You would need to set `mtextFontInherit` to `true` in the `"HTML-CSS"` section of your configuration for that.